# Why sort_order in a table when we can sort it by using keyword ORDER BY

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I was going through a database (learning database) and found sort_order in a few table.

[image]

What could be the purpose sort_order in this table?.

If it (as I think) is for sorting, we could use "ORDER BY" in the query for sorting.

Comment: Indeed its for deciding the order of the data and used for order by

Comment: Yes, but what are you going to put in your `ORDER BY` clause?

Comment: Becasue that way it's ordered on the disk, and doesn't have to be re-ordered (sorted) at runtime.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, right. I started having a hold of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the comments to your question have answered it. Let me explain the reasoning behind the design pattern you are observing.

The ORDER BY clause requires a field on the table that it will use to order the returned data (ascending or descending). Most tables have a field that makes sense to order the content by, however, what if you wanted the user to individually order a list of items i.e. you want a customisable order. In such cases a numeric field can be added to the table like the one you have spotted. The custom order is saved to this field, such that the first item in the list has sort_order=1, the second item has sort_order=2...and the nth item has sort_order=n.

Now if you query the data and use ORDER BY sort_order, you will get the list out in the exact order your user dictated.

In your particular example the design allows the user to define a custom order for the list of pictures to appear in, so they can say the first picture has sort_order=1, the second has sort_order=2 ...

HTH